# T test inherently continuous variables

Tags: self-study, t-test, chi-squared-test

I had a linear regression assignment I just got feedback on. I decided to categorize a covariate in the model.  I understand the loss of information when using categorization and this question. In this problem I am looking at body mass index (BMI). When I compiled Table 1 which compares all possible covariates between the case and control groups, I used a chi-square test for the variables that would be categorical in a linear regression model. When I got the feedback on the assignment, I was asked why I used a chi square test for BMI, rather than a t-test since it is inherently continuous. I chose the chi square test because I was treating it as categorical. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is it possible that the grader missed the point that you had treated BMI as categorical rather than continuous? Or that the feedback was a way of saying you shouldn't have categorized BMI in the first place? (Some might even argue you shouldn't use BMI as a variable at all, and use instead body mass and some measure of body dimension like height or surface area as separate covariates, but that's also another discussion.)

Comment: I do think you should treat BMI as continuous because as you mentioned you lose information when you put it into categorical groups.  It would help to know what the dependent variable is for the regression model. Whether or not the t distribution should be used for BMI would depend on its distribution for the patients.  If it is not symmetric a normal distribution would not be appropriate and the t test would not apply. You neglected to mention what the sample size is. I disagree with EdM about using other body related measurements since they may not be available.

Comment: Since this is an assignment we require that you include the self-study tag.